# Read html tags from xml file using java

Tags: java, html, xml-parsing

I'm using xml parser (DocumentBuilderFactory) to parse the xml data(I/p obtained from API calls) inside my Java code. I have some html tags(style information) inside an xml node which I want to retain but parser ignores those tags by treating them as xml tags and reads the text content between them.

For example:

```
<xmltag1 type="">
<div id=""> 
<p> text content1 </p>
</div>
</xmltag1>
```

When I parse the above xml node 'xmltag1', I'm only able to read 'text content1' though the html tags are included in between the xml tags. Please help.

PS: I do not have any control over the i/p (xml data) so I can't use CDATA section.

Comment: How are you trying to read those elements currently? The html is kind of subset of XML so, you must be omitting the `div` and `p` while querying the `xmltag1` currently.

Comment: Please show your code and create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should also read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).